# AdWords Script - Set Active Account

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I have a manager account which manages ~50 client accounts. I am trying to build a custom report for each managed account by iterating through them and pulling info from each one. So I have:

```
//Get an iterator for the managed accounts
var accountIterator = MccApp.accounts()
.withCondition("ManagerCustomerId = 'my id is here'")
.get();

while(accountIterator.hasNext()) {
    var currentAccount = accountIterator.next();
    //TODO: retrieve information about campaigns under 'currentAccount'
}
```

Looking at the [reference provided by google](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/adwordsapp/adwordsapp) I have found the AdWordsApp.currentAccount() function. I would like to know how to change the value returned by that function so that I can use the other AdWordsApp functions to get the info I want.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with [this guide.](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/features/mcc) I just need to use `MccApp.select(currentAccount);`. I was thinking this wouldn't work because I thought the current account according to MccApp was different from the current AdWordsApp account, but they are the same.